# Printing the properties of a class

Tags: python-3.x

I want to print x and y by using by printPerson, but I can't get the solution to fix it. When i try to use x.printPerson it states that printPerson is not defined. How come?

```
class Person:
    def __init__ (self, name, age, strong, vehicle):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.strong = strong
        self.vehicle = vehicle

    def printPerson(self):
        print("Name:" + self.name)
        print("Age:" + self.age)
        print("Strong:" + self.strong)
        print("Vehicle:" + self.vehicle)            

x = Person("x", 20, ["Strong", "Strong", "Strong"], ["Car" , "Bike"])
y = Person("y",21, ["Weak", "Weak", "Super weak"], ["bus", "tractor"])
```

And how can I print x that the output is as following:

```
>>> x.printPerson()

Name: x
Age: 20
Strong: "Strong, Strong, Strong"
Vehicle: "Car, Bike"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
x.printPerson()
```

Rather than:

```
x.printPerson
```

Full Code:

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__ (self, name, age, strong, vehicle):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.strong = strong
        self.vehicle = vehicle

    def printPerson(self):
        print("Name:" + self.name)
        print("Age:" + str(self.age))
        print("Strong:" + ", ".join([val for val in self.strong]))
        print("Vehicle:" + ", ".join([val for val in self.vehicle]))

x = Person("x", 20, ["Strong", "Strong", "Strong"], ["Car" , "Bike"])

x.printPerson()
```